# Sobolev Spaces and the Zygmund Class estimate

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I am trying to solve the following problem-
$$
$$
Given $∈H^2(^2)$, show that it satisfies:

$|(+2)−2(+)+()|≤||$

$ \forall x,y \in R^2$

for some constant $c$.
$$
$$
Here, 
$$
H^{2}(R^2)=\{f:R^{2} \to R: D^{\alpha}f \in L^{2}(R^{2}) \;  \forall |\alpha| \leq 2 \} 
$$
With norm
$$
||f||_{H^2}= ( \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 2} ||D^{\alpha}f||_{2}^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Where $\alpha \in (N \cup \{0\})^{2}$ multi-index and $D^{\alpha}f$ is the weak $\alpha$-derivative of $f$.
$$
$$
So far, taking the definition of Fourier transform and it's inverse to be:
$$
\hat{f}(\epsilon)=\int_{R^n}f(x)e^{i \epsilon \cdot x}dx \; \text{and} \; \check{f}(x)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \int_{R^n}f(\epsilon)e^{-i \epsilon \cdot x} d \epsilon,
$$
I have that 
$$
|f(x+2y)-2f(x+y)+f(x)| = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^2}\int_{R^2} \hat{f}(\epsilon) \; (e^{-2i \epsilon \cdot y}- 2e^{-i\epsilon \cdot y}+1)\; e^{-i \epsilon \cdot x} \;d \epsilon .
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\leq\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \; (\int_{R^2} |\hat{f}|^2(1+|\epsilon_{1}|^2+|\epsilon_{2}|^2)^{2} d \epsilon)^{\frac{1}{2}} \;(\int_{R^2}|e^{-2i \epsilon \cdot y}- 2e^{-i\epsilon \cdot y}+1|^{2} \; (1+|\epsilon_{1}|^2+|\epsilon_{2}|^2)^{-2} d\epsilon)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
I am aware that
$$
(\int_{R^2} |\hat{f}|^2(1+|\epsilon_{1}|^2+|\epsilon_{2}|^2)^{2} d \epsilon)
$$
can be bounded by a constant multiple of $||f||_{H^{2}}^{2}$ using Plancherel's formula in $L^{2}$ and the Fourier transforms of derivatives. 
$$
$$
I am not sure what to about 
$$
\int_{R^2}|e^{-2i \epsilon \cdot y}- 2e^{-i\epsilon \cdot y}+1|^{2} \; (1+|\epsilon_{1}|^2+|\epsilon_{2}|^2)^{-2} d\epsilon.$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You were downvoted (not by me) probably because you asked in the imperative without showing any effort. That's considered rude and strongly discouraged, here.

Comment: Thank you for telling me @GiuseppeNegro . I was unaware. Should I write out what I've been trying so far?

Comment: That's a good idea.